# How to use ancestor's EventBus if I am extending Widget in GWT?

Tags: java, events, gwt, customization

I am extending a `ScrollPanel` and wish to process my own custom events with this new widget.

I made my own `HasMyHandlers` interface with two methods `fireEvent(MyEvent event)` and `HandlerRegistration addMyHandler(MyHandler handler)`.

First I made a private member `SimpleEventBus eventBus`, but next thought that the ancestor class should already have it's own copy.

Is it possible to use ancestor's event bus, i.e. to register handlers within it and to fire them according to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The standard way to do this is in the implementation of `HandlerRegistration addMyHandler(MyHandler handler)` is :

```
public class MyWidget extends Widget implements HasMyHandlers {

  @Override
  public HandlerRegistration addMyHandler(MyHandler handler) { 
    return addHandler(handler, MyEvent.getType());
  }

  // Other methods
}
```

The `Widget.addHandler(...)` method provides the mechanism to wire custom event handlers to the Widget's HandlerManager.

To fire your event to all registered handlers you use `Widget.fireEvent(...)` method. So to fire your event you can do:

```
fireEvent(new MyEvent(yourEventData));
```

It's worth noting that your event should also extend the `GwtEvent` class.

Comment: But how to fire event to all registered handlers when it occurs?

Comment: @Dims I've added some more detail to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. But since Widget.fireEvent accepts argument of type GwtEvent<> this means that I am obliged to extend the class with my events, right?

Comment: To use `Widget.fireEvent` you do have to extend it. But it's a handy class with several useful event related methods. Check out the docs.